# reading csv from pyspark specifying schema wrong types

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I am trying to output csv from a pyspark df an then re inputting it, but when I specify schema, for a column that is an array, it says that some of the rows are `False`.

Here is my `df`

```
   avg(rating)  belongs_to_collection    budget  \
0     2.909946                  False   5000000   
1     3.291962                  False  18000000   
2     3.239811                  False   8000000   
3     3.573318                  False   1500000   
4     3.516590                  False  40000000   

                                      genres original_language  
0                       ['Drama', 'Romance']                en  
1                                 ['Comedy']                en  
2                        ['Drama', 'Family']                en  
3  ['Crime', 'Drama', 'Mystery', 'Thriller']                en  
4             ['Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']                en
```

I first output to csv: `df.drop('id').toPandas().to_csv('mergedDf.csv',index=False)`

I tried reading using `df = spark.read.csv('mergedDf.csv',schema=schema)`, but I get this error: `'CSV data source does not support array<string> data type.;'`

So, I tried reading from pandas and then converting to spark df, but it tells me that the column that contains a list has a boolean value.

```
df = pd.read_csv('mergedDf.csv')
df = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema=schema)
TypeError: field genres: ArrayType(StringType,true) can not accept object False in type <class 'bool'>
```

However, when I check if some of the rows are == to False, I find that none of them are.

I checked :
`df[df['genres']=="False"]` and `df[df['genres']==False]`

Comment: The error "TypeError: field genres: ArrayType(StringType,true) can not accept object False in type <class 'bool'>" clearly indicates that you have provided wrong typed data....so how did you check False condition ? using df.filter () ??

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, spark read csv function doesn't yet support complex datatypes like "array". You would have handle the logic of cast the string column into array column

Use pandas to write the spark dataframe as csv with header.

```
df.drop('id').toPandas().to_csv('mergedDf.csv',index=False,header=True)
df1 = spark.read.option('header','true').option("inferSchema","true").csv('mergedDf.csv')
df1.printSchema()
df1.show(10,False)
```

When you read back csv with spark, the array column would be convert to string type

```
root
 |-- avg(rating): double (nullable = true)
 |-- belongs_to_collection: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- budget: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- genres: string (nullable = true)
 |-- original_language: string (nullable = true)

+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
|avg(rating)|belongs_to_collection|budget  |genres                                   |original_language|
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
|2.909946   |false                |5000000 |['Drama', 'Romance']                     |en               |
|3.291962   |false                |18000000|['Comedy']                               |en               |
|3.239811   |false                |8000000 |['Drama', 'Family']                      |en               |
|3.573318   |false                |1500000 |['Crime', 'Drama', 'Mystery', 'Thriller']|en               |
|3.51659    |false                |40000000|['Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']           |en               |
+-----------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Split the string column to create an array to get back your original format.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn('genres',split(regexp_replace(col('genres'), '\[|\]',''),',').cast('array<string>'))
df2.printSchema()
```

.

```
root
 |-- avg(rating): double (nullable = true)
 |-- belongs_to_collection: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- budget: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- genres: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- original_language: string (nullable = true)
```